# Bower build failing with "art://" in the artifactory url

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, url-rewriting, bower, artifactory

We are building a bower project on jenkins and it is failing with this error:

```
[ERROR] bower angular#1.3.2   EINVRES Request to https://repo.mycompany.com/api/bower/bower-repo/packages/art%3A%2F%2Fangular%2Fbower-angular
failed with 400
```

The URL string contains `art://angular/bower-angular` at the end, which results in an invalid URL.

If I type the following url in my browser, the artifact exists here:

`https://repo.mycompany.com/bower-repo/angular/bower-angular/`

We are using artifactory v4, set up with maven, npm and bower repositories (local and cache).

My question is this: what is going on here with the `art://`? Should artifactory be able to understand this, or is there some "url rewriting" that needs to happen here?

---

Edit: adding config

```
[jenkins@myserver angular-app]$ more bower.json
{
  "name": "com.mycompany.myapp.web.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/app.js",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.2",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.2",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.2",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.2",
    "angular-i18n": "1.3.2",
    "lodash": "2.4.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.13",
    "angular-translate": "2.3.0",
    "angular-busy": "4.1.1",
    "angular-promise-tracker": "2.0.1",
    "jquery-ui": "1.9.2",
    "jquery": "2.1.1",
    "ionicons": "2.0.0",
    "modernizr": "2.8.3",
    "angular-ui-utils": "validate-0.2.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.2",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.4",
    "my-internal-lib-intern": "git+https://xxx.mycompany.com/scm/abc/my-internal-lib-intern.git#feature/my-feature"
  },
  "appPath": "./",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.4"
  }
}

[jenkins@myserver angular-app]$ more ~/.bowerrc
{
"registry": "https://xxx.my-company.com/api/bower/bower-repo",
"resolvers" : [
    "bower-art-resolver"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the bower.json you are using and the relevant .bowerrc configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

The `art://` schema is an indication for Bower to use the [bower-art-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-art-resolver) for resolving packages from Artifactory. Bower has the ability to use custom resolvers instead of the default one which resolves from Github.
This specific issue seem to be related to using an old version of this resolver. To solve the issue, make sure you are using the latest version of Bower and the resolver. Try updating the resolver by running (latest version is 2.0.4):

```
npm install -g bower-art-resolver
```

With the new version of bower-art-resolver your configuration should be something like:

```
{
  "registry": {
      "register": "https://bower.herokuapp.com",
      "search": [
        "https://xxx.my-company.com/api/bower/bower-repo"
      ]
    },
  "resolvers" : [
      "bower-art-resolver"
    ]
}
```